# Proving by induction this inequality

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction

I need to prove by induction that $f(n) \geq 2^{n-1}$ when $n$ is a power of $2$, if I know that $f(n) \geq 2 f^2(n/2)$ when $n$ is also a power of $2$. I'm stuck at the inductive step. Let $n = 2^i$ where $i = 0, 1, 2, \dots$. Assume $f(2^i) \geq 2^{2^i-1}$ holds. From here I can get $f(2^{i+1}) \geq 2f^{2}(2^i)\geq 2^{2^i}f(2^i)\geq2^{2^i}$. Thus, $f(2^{i+1}) \geq 2^{2^i}$, which is not exactly what I should get ($f(2^{i+1}) \geq 2^{2^{i+1}-1}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(2^{i+1})\geq 2f^{2}(2^i)\geq 2\left(2^{2^i-1}\right)^2=2^{1+2(2^i-1)}=2^{2^{i+1}-1}.$